# Upper Case all First Characters in a string Except certain words

Tags: php

This convert the First Character of every word in a string to UpperCase

```
echo ucwords("hello world"); // Result : Hello World
```

How can I do the same except for certain words

example : `new york branch 2 br property jbr`

Should display : `New York Branch 2 br Property jbr`

// `br` and `jbr` are excluded from conversion but the `br` in the word `branch` is not affected by the exclusion

Comment: If I handed you a stack of paper slips, all with one line of text on them like your example above, and asked you to rewrite the line of text but capitalize the first letter of certain words.. then hand the slip of paper back to me.. what would you do? Think about how you would do this in steps in real life. For example, a good first step would probably be to inspect the line of text perhaps from left to right and see if there are any words in it that we need to capitalize.. writing methods or functions in programming often works best when we just translate real life steps in to code.

Comment: probably you should use regular expression to replace this type of string.

Answer (score 0):

**1.You try doing it by first splitting the string by blank space like:**

```
 $beforeb="new york branch 2 br property jbr"
 $afters=explode(" ",$beforeb);
```

**2.Now using for each loop you can match every string and convert it into upper case if it doesnot with  words like br or jbr,and store it to an array ex,$array1[]**

```
foreach($afters as $caseup){
$i=0;

 if($caseup=="br" || $caseup=="jbr"){   //selected words you dont want to make uppercase
   $array1[i]=$caseup;
 }
 else{
  $array1[i]=ucwords($caseup);
  }
  }
```

**3.Then again convert the $array1[] into a string using implode() method**